# JQuery onClick map link show <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good morning,

I'm trying to create a simple loading effect (really simple) with JQuery but I cannot find the solution.

I would like to show a div (with a message: "Loading") when a user clicks on a map area, but it's not working.

That's my code:

JQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#cargando').on('click', function() {
        $('#box-info').css("display","block");
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
#box-info{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="box-info"><div class="box-info">Loading...<br></div></div>
<AREA id="cargando" SHAPE="rect" ALT="Melilla" COORDS="411,396,434,410" HREF="http://www.idermo.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119&Itemid=876&provincia=Melilla"/>
```

I tried that code on a Fiddle and it worked with a `<a></a>` but it didn't worked with a `<map area>`. What I have to change in my code in order to make this work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/12/

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: Would you mind providing a fiddle, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js` is loading **jQuery UI** library. You need to load jQuery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/12/) you are using `id="cargando"` multiple times, **IDs must be unique**

Comment: How can I use different IDs but with the same JQuery effect? Because I don't want to make something like:-----------------$('#cargando1').on('click', function() {$('.box-info').css("display","block");});--------------------
 $('#cargando2').on('click', function() {$('.box-info').css("display","block");});

Comment: @Wiraj, give a common css class to both elements then use class selector like `$('.cargando')`.